# In express is there a performance difference between requiring a module within a route versus outside?

Tags: node.js, express

**inside the route:**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var module = require('module');
    module.doathing();
});
```

**outside the route:**

```
var module = require('module');
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    module.doathing();
});
```

Does doing it outside make it load the module every time the page is loaded, no matter the route?

Comment: You bring up a good question, but if memory serves me right, the performance difference is minimal. You should always code for readability before performance when it comes to these types of micro-improvements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `require()` function uses synchronous I/O to load modules.  So, the first time the module is loaded, it will use some synchronous I/O (after that the module will be cached so it won't have to be loaded over and over).  It is generally bad to use synchronous I/O from a request handler because that compromises the scalability of the single threaded node.js event driven system.

So, in general, **you should not use `require()` inside an event handler**.  It should generally be used at server initialization time only when synchronous I/O does not hurt your server's scalability.

> In express is there a performance difference between requiring a module within a route versus outside?

Yes, there is a difference - see above explanation.  You should do the `require()` at server initialization time, not at run-time in the route.